# How are viruses made for windows?

Tags: windows, exploit, virus, exploit-development, windows-permissions

I know that windows source code is proprietary so how do hackers and others know what are the available exploits in windows so that the viruses can take their advantage.

Comment: For example by fuzzing. your question shows a lack of understanding in many different fields of computer science and is thus way too broad for this format to be answered. I'll VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The computer still has to be able to execute a program and therefore you have the machine code available. Figuring out how a program works from there is the most common form of  **reverse engineering**.
2. You don't have to exploit windows to write a virus for windows. People run all kinds of programs on windows and it's enough to exploit any one of them.